# Compute the integral $ \int_0^\infty e^{-u^\ell} u^m du $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function

I have a general formula,
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-u^\ell} u^m du
$$
that I wish to solve. I have seen that that the solution is some combination of incomplete Gamma functions in most cases, but I would appreciate a little bit of in-depth explanation as to how to get there.

To clarify, $u, \ell, m$ are all real.

Thanks!

EDIT: In addition to this, $u$ is always positive.

Comment: You already have the right answer, but here is some other advice. I recommend investigating integrals like this on Wolfram Alpha by plugging in various values for your parameters. You will often be able to figure out the pattern, then you can figure out how to get the pattern.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I gave Wolfram Alpha a try, but the limits broke it, and unfortunately I do not have access to the pro compute time. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u^l=x, u=x^{1/l}, du=\frac1lx^{1/l-1}dx$

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-u^l} u^m du=\frac1l\int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{\frac{m+1}l-1} ~dx=\frac1l\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}l\right)
$$